# How do I correlate TAB keypresses + mouse clicks with mouseenter, mouseleave Events?

Tags: jquery

How do I correlate TAB keypresses + mouse clicks with mouseenter, mouseleave Events?

**Big** picture = CSS and Javascript driven drop-menus + sub-menus.

The **challenge** is that when I execute mouseenter/mouseleave Events within `setupHoverOverMainMenu()` seen below, I wish to click on any item within the `$itsHoverMainMenu`.

Note that both mouseenter and mouseleave Events begin with `getFocusedItem()` which reflects the new focused item changed with either TAB keypresses or mouse clicks.

```
function getFocusedItem() {

    return $(document.activeElement);
    
}
```

Within mouseenter, I hide `$itsPrevDropMenu` and show `$itsHoverMainMenu`.

(The global `$itsPrevDropMenu` is determined via TAB keypresses in a separate function)

I get `$itsPrevFocusedItem` within `mouseenter`.

I compare `$itsPrevFocusedItem` with `$itsNewFocusedItem` within `mouseleave` and act accordingly.

If I have **not** clicked on a different item, I want to hide `$itsHoverMainMenu` and re-show `$itsPrevDropMenu`. **This seems to work.**

If I have clicked on a new item, I keep `$itsPrevDropMenu` hidden and keep `$itsHoverMainMenu` visible. **This not so much.**

**Note**

(1) `showMenu` sets the passed menu's css to `.css("left", "auto")`

(2) `hideMenu` sets the passed menu's css to `.css("left", "-99999px")`

```
function setupHoverOverMainMenu() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        var $itsHoverMainMenu = {},
            $itsNewMainMenu,
            $itsPrevFocusedItem,
            $itsNewFocusedItem;

        $("#menubar > li").on({   // top menubar items, either drop or non-drop menus
    
            mouseenter: function(evt) {
        
                $itsPrevFocusedItem = getFocusedItem();
                
                if ($itsPrevDropMenu.length > 0)
                {
                    hideMenu($itsPrevDropMenu);
                //  $itsPrevDropMenu = {};   // TABs + clicks set this, so don't mess!
                }
            
                if ($(this).hasClass("drop"))
                {
                    $itsHoverMainMenu = $(this)
                                           .find(".aMenu")
                                           .first();
                    showMenu($itsHoverMainMenu);
                }
                
            },   // mouseenter
            
            mouseleave: function(evt) {
            
                // we may have clicked a <li> during mouseenter
                $itsNewFocusedItem = getFocusedItem();
                if (($itsNewFocusedItem.length > 0) &&
                    ($itsNewFocusedItem[0] !== $itsPrevFocusedItem[0]))
                {
                    $itsNewMainMenu = $itsNewFocusedItem
                                         .closest("drop")
                                         .find(".aMenu")
                                         .first();
                    if (($itsNewMainMenu.length > 0) &&
                        ($itsNewMainMenu[0] !== $itsPrevDropMenu[0]))
                    {
                        showMenu($itsNewMainMenu);
                    //  $itsPrevDropMenu = $itsNewMainMenu;   // TABs + clicks set this
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $itsNewMainMenu = getOtherMainMenu($itsNewFocusedItem);
                        if (($itsNewMainMenu.length > 0) &&
                            ($itsNewMainMenu[0] !== $itsPrevDropMenu[0]))
                        {
                            showMenu($itsNewMainMenu);
                        //  $itsPrevDropMenu = $itsNewMainMenu;   // TABs + clicks set this
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // = new focused item = *not* any menu,
                            // but an individual <li> item
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($itsHoverMainMenu.length > 0)
                        hideMenu($itsHoverMainMenu);

                    if ($itsPrevDropMenu.length > 0)
                        showMenu($itsPrevDropMenu);
                }
                
            }   // mouseleave
        
        });   // on
    
    });   // ready
    
}   // setupHoverOverMainMenu
```

Comment: This looks like overengineering. Menus & submenus with just CSS is a solved problem; a little searching would find many implementations on the web. In any case, note that `setupHoverOverMainMenu` adds event handlers, but does not remove them, so if it's called more than once, the events will trigger multiple copies of those handlers, which might not be what you want.

Comment: You are correct = CSS menus/submenus is a solved problem and, starting way way back when with Suckerfish Menus, that's done on my end. I think I latched onto Suckerfish Menus about 7 years ago to start that adventure. I then went in the direction of TAB keypresses for the very 1st time and what another adventure ... now TABs are also done on my end. With TABs, I got my wish to keep the drop menus and sub menus visible when TABbed to - unlike hovering which come and go. Again .. done. Comment continued below ...

Comment: Now, I'm trying to inject mouse clicks while hovering so the drop menus stay visible just as with TABbing. Your comments about not removing mouseenter and mouseleave requires a whole bunch of deep thinking here. I promise that. I cannot possibly thank you enough for spending your time on my problem.